# What is the differences between container.__iter__() and iterator.__iter__()?

Tags: python

I am poor in python so don't beat me please.

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a.__iter__()
<listiterator object at 0x03531750>
>>> a.__iter__().__iter__()
<listiterator object at 0x03531690>
```

I see that both of listiterator objects lives in other places (true that `0x03531750` is like place?). I need to know that both of these objects are the same, but lives in other places or they are different?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would seriously doubt that those 2 things are the same. Unless `listiterator.__iter__` just returns `self`.

Comment: i want to see this. From where can i import listiterator to try `__iter__` method on it?

Comment: @Cadilac: You don't import it, you don't even create one explicitly. It's created when you call `iter` on a list.

Comment: Of course. It is so clear that i missed that for a while. Thank You.

Comment: Don't worry, we don't beat people here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An iterator has an `__iter__()` method so that you can call `iter()` on it to get an iterator for it, even though it already is one. Makes it easier to write things that use iterators if you don't have to be constantly checking whether something is already an iterator or not.

So you're getting an iterator for the list, and then getting an iterator for that iterator. An iterator for an iterator is the original iterator (Python doesn't create a second iterator, there's no point).

OK, good so far.

Iterators are objects and, like all objects, have a lifecycle. They are created when you call `__iter__()` (or `iter()`) on the object and destroyed when there are no longer any references to them.  In your example, you do `a.__iter__()`, which creates the list iterator. Then, since you don't keep a reference to the it anywhere, this iterator is destroyed more or less immediately (though this is an implementation detail).  So your next command, `a.__iter__().__iter__()` creates a *new* iterator for the list (only one, because the iterator of an iterator is the same iterator) -- it does not reuse the iterator you made in the previous command, because that iterator is gone. This is why the objects have different IDs; they are in fact different objects.

You will see that `a.__iter__()` and `a.__iter__().__iter__()` are the same object if you keep a reference to the former. Try this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = iter(a)    # a.__iter__()
j = iter(i)    # i.__iter__() which is a.__iter__().__iter__()
print i is j   # True, they're the same object
```

Comment: If i getting an iterator for the list, and then geting an iterator for that iterator, python don't create new iterator, but if i try to iterate over container python localize this same iterator in two virtual memory places or just in one?

Comment: If you have an iterator, and you get the iterator of that, it's always the same iterator. Since it's the same iterator, it is in the same memory location by definition. You can get two different iterators of a list, though.

Comment: That explains something to me. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

`iter(iterable)` returns an iterator so that you may call (explicitly or implicitly e.g., via a `for`-loop) `next(iterator)` to get the next item from the `iterable` or receive `StopIteration` exception.

`iter(iterator)` should return itself:

```
>>> it = iter([])
>>> it is iter(it)
True
```

Forget about memory locations e.g., jython, pypy would return something different.

Comment: I will try forget about memory locations. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

0x03531690 is the virtual memory location of the object and basically it tells you nothing

e.g.:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a.__iter__()
<listiterator object at 0x102d70d90>
>>> a.__iter__()
<listiterator object at 0x102d70e10>
```

I don't know what you are trying to do adding another List Iterator to a List Iterator that iterates over a list of characters :)

Comment: Docs say: One method needs to be defined for container objects to provide iteration support:
`container.__iter__()`
The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:
`iterator.__iter__()`. And i just thinking about `iterator.__iter__()`. But if both are the same it is enought for me to go further.